# viewing XML like that of IE on Vista with TWebBrowser

Tags: xml, delphi, internet-explorer, xslt, twebbrowser

On XP this code worked fine if I wanted to view XML in a `TWebBrowser`:

```
uses ComObj, MSHTML, ActiveX;

procedure DocumentFromString(ABrowser: TWebBrowser; const HTMLString: wideString);
var
  v: OleVariant;
  HTMLDocument: IHTMLDocument2;
begin
  if not Assigned(ABrowser.Document) then
  begin
    ABrowser.Navigate('about:blank');
    while ABrowser.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
    begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      Sleep(0);
    end;
  end;
  HTMLDocument := ABrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  v := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
  v[0] := HTMLString;
  HTMLDocument.Write(PSafeArray(TVarData(v).VArray));
  HTMLDocument.Close;
end;

procedure WebBrowserXML(ABrowser: TWebBrowser; const XmlString: WideString);
var
  xml, xsl: OleVariant;
  HTMLString: WideString;
begin
  xml := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument');
  xml.async := False;
  xml.loadXML(XmlString);
  // Assert(xml.parseError.errorCode = 0);
  xsl := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument');
  xsl.validateOnParse := False;
  xsl.async := False;
  xsl.load('res://msxml.dll/defaultss.xsl');
  // Assert(xsl.parseError.errorCode = 0);
  HTMLString := xml.transformNode(xsl);
  ABrowser.HandleNeeded;
  DocumentFromString(ABrowser, HTMLString);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowserXML(WebBrowser1, '<xml><node>Hello</node></xml>');
end;
```

The method is as followed: the **XML** is transformed with **XSLT** (`defaultss.xsl`) and the result is **HTML**.

On Vista I get an exeption in the line `xml.transformNode(xsl);`:

> The stylesheet does not caontain a document element. The stylesheet
>   may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML document

I have tried to directly load my own copy of XSLT from file like this `xsl.load('my.xsl')`:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1141304.aspx?xslt+viewing+XML+like+that+of+IE

but still I get the same error that the XSLT is not valid.

How do I make this code work on Vista?

---

From the comments to the [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1141304.aspx?xslt%20viewing%20XML%20like%20that%20of%20IE) I provided:

> I have also found that after calling directly into
>   **res://msxml#.dll/defaultss.xsl** for years, this method no longer works
>   in Vista.  I've messed with all sorts of security settings, but that
>   does not seem to be the issue. It looks like my only option is to
>   release my own copy of defaultss.xsl.

I can't seem to provide a valid "my own copy" of `defaultss.xsl`. they all fail with the same exception error. what can I do?

Comment: Did you verify that the `load()` is actually succeeding before you call `transformNode()`? Did you verify that the `res:` URL is valid?  When I try to load that URL into IE11, it can't access it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Yes I verified all. `xsl.load()` fails. This is exactlly the probelm: there is no valid `res://msxml.dll/defaultss.xsl`. I don't mind using my own xslt which I can embed in my exe res, as long as it is valid xslt - which I can't make work.

Comment: [`load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722.aspx) accepts a lot of different values as input. If you can't load it by URL (BTW, the documentation shows an example that uses `res://msxml3.dll/xml/defaultss.xsl` instead) or by filename (which you are specifying by relative path, try using an absolute path instead), then try loading the actual xslt data as an `IStream` or a `PSafeArray` of bytes.

Comment: If you want to embed the xslt as a resource in your app, just make sure you use a `res:` URL that refers to your app. See [MSDN's  documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740.aspx) for that syntax.

Comment: I just checked on Windows 7 and `msxml3.dll` does have an `XML` resource named `DEFAULTSS.XSL`, but `msxml4.dll` and `msxml6.dll` do not, and there is no `msxml.dll` file. As MSDN says, `res:` defaults to `/html/` or `/file/` if you don't specify a resource type. so `res:msxml3.dll/defaultss.xls` shouldn't work since the resource is `XML`, thus use `res:msxml2.dll/xml/defaults.xls` instead.

Comment: so `res://msxml3.dll/defaultss.xls` shouldn't work since the resource type is `XML`, thus use `res://msxml3.dll/xml/defaults.xls` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `res://C:%5Cwindows%5Csystem32%5Cmsxml3.dll/XML/DEFAULTSS.XSL` and `res://msxml3.dll/XML/DEFAULTSS.XSL` worked ok on Vista. please make an answer.

Comment: You don't need to specify the full system path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`load()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722.aspx) shows an example that uses this URL:

```
res://msxml3.dll/xml/defaultss.xsl
```

If you want to embed an XSLT as a resource in your app, just make sure you use a `res:` URL that refers to that resource in your app. See MSDN's documentation for that syntax:

[res Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740.aspx)

> Syntax
>
> ```
> res://sFile[/sType]/sID
> ```
>
> Tokens
>
> sFile
>   Percent-encoded path and file name of the module that contains the resource.
>
> sType
>   Optional. String or numerical resource type. This can be either a custom resource or one of the predefined resource types that are recognized by the FindResource function. If a numerical resource type is specified, the number of the identifier must follow a # character. **If this parameter is not specified, the default resource type is RT_HTML or RT_FILE.**
>
> sID
>   String or numerical identifier of the resource. If a numerical identifier is specified, the actual number of the identifier, not the identifier itself, must follow a # character.

I just checked on Windows 7 and `msxml3.dll` does have an `XML` resource named `DEFAULTSS.XSL`, but `msxml4.dll` and `msxml6.dll` do not, and there is no `msxml.dll` file.

As MSDN says, `res:` defaults to `HTML` or `FILE` if a resource type is not specified, so using  `res://msxml3.dll/defaultss.xls` will not work since the XSLT resource type is `XML` instead.  Thus, you need to use `res://msxml3.dll/xml/defaultss.xls` instead.